# GET request with nested parameters

Tags: search, get, request

I'm working on a simple search engine to let users filter professional profiles based on some criteria.

Let's say I'm looking for a profile able to speak two languages, italian(1) and spanish(2): a `GET` request could look like `...&languages=1,2&...`.

But, let's say I'm looking for a profile able to speak italian(1) very good(10) and spanish(2) quite good(9).

How to structure a GET request for this instance?

Answer (score 1):

Easy as `...&languages[1]=10&languages[2]=9&...`